# Getting error in C, control reaches end of non-void function

Tags: c, compiler-errors, return, warnings, compiler-warnings

Consider the following function:

```
off_t
func (const struct inode *inode)
{
  off_t length = 0;
  read_cache (&length, inode->sector, offsetof (struct inode_disk, length), sizeof (off_t));
  return length;
}
```

I am getting both an error and also a warning:

```
error: expected declaration or statement at end of input
warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
```

The line at which both the error and warning points to is the last line which controls the closing bracket of the function.

When i searched, i found that this error comes when the return type of function is non-void, and we are not returning anything.
But that is not the case here.

Please help !

EDIT:

Following contains the function above that function as well as that function as it appears in the source code:

```
/* Re-enables writes to INODE.
   Must be called once by each inode opener who has called
   inode_deny_write() on the inode, before closing the inode. */
void
inode_allow_write (struct inode *inode) 
{
  ASSERT (inode->deny_write_cnt > 0);
  ASSERT (inode->deny_write_cnt <= inode->open_cnt);
  inode->deny_write_cnt--;
}

/* Returns the length, in bytes, of INODE's data. */
off_t
inode_length (const struct inode *inode)
{
  off_t length = 0;
  read_cache (&length, inode->sector, offsetof (struct inode_disk, length), sizeof (off_t));
  return length;
}
```

I dont think i am missing some curly brace etc. at the function above it.

Comment: My guess is that you are missing a curly brace or a semicolon somewhere above this declaration in the same translation unit.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: I have edited the question to include the function above the problem causing function. I dont think i am missing a semicolon/bracket.

Comment: Is `ASSERT` your macro? Or from somewhere else? Any chance the macro is missing a closing curly brace? One way or the other, you have a flow control statement (if, while, do, for) or a function that is missing a closing curly brace.

Comment: @KScottPiel Yes, ASSERT is a macro.. and it is not missing curly brace. I checked and also this macro is being used at other places and working perfectly.

Comment: OKay... so the only advice is to work backwards to find the missing curly brace. The compiler isn't telling you the name of the function? Whatever function it thinks is reaching the end of control is the one that is missing the closing curly brace.

Comment: How long is the source file? I would suggest you post the entire source if you can. That way we can look at it to spot where you made the formatting error. Alternatively, put it in C editor that does syntax checking (Eclipse/VisualStudio/etc) and see where it starts complaining.

Comment: @KScottPiel : GOT IT ! Thanks a ton !! I moved backwards... and while backtracing, i found that some earlier function had a missing curly brace. Thanks !!